# R: short and effective code for a sequence of lm models from DOE factors

Tags: r, sequence, paste

Background:
I have several responses as output from an DOE and want to model each one. First and of course successfull try was to simply write a long code for each model.

```
formula<- y~a+b+c+d+a:b+a:c+a:d+b:c+b:d+c:d+I(a^2)+I(b^2)+I(c^2)+I(d^2)

Response_Data <- dataframe%>%
  dplyr::select(2:5,6)
a <- Response_Data$X1
b <- Response_Data$X2
c <- Response_Data$X3
d <- Response_Data$X4
y <- Response_Data[[5]]
Response_1_Model <- lm(formula,Response_Data)

Response_Data <- dataframe%>%
  dplyr::select(2:5,7)
a <- Response_Data$X1
b <- Response_Data$X2
c <- Response_Data$X3
d <- Response_Data$X4
y <- Response_Data[[5]]
Response_2_Model <- lm(formula,Response_Data)

Response_Data <- dataframe%>%
  dplyr::select(2:5,8)
a <- Response_Data$X1
b <- Response_Data$X2
c <- Response_Data$X3
d <- Response_Data$X4
y <- Response_Data[[5]]
Response_3_Model <- lm(formula,Response_Data)

and so on, and so on
```

then I wanted to have all coefficients in one dataframe and did this:

```
Coefficients<-data.frame(Response_1_Model%>%coef(),Response_2_Model%>%coef(),Response_3_Model%>%coef(),Response_4_Model%>%coef(),Response_5_Model%>%coef(),Response_6_Model%>%coef(),Response_7_Model%>%coef(),Response_8_Model%>%coef(),Response_9_Model%>%coef(),Response_10_Model%>%coef(),Response_11_Model%>%coef(),Response_12_Model%>%coef(),Response_13_Model%>%coef(),Response_14_Model%>%coef(),Response_15_Model%>%coef(),Response_16_Model%>%coef(),Response_17_Model%>%coef(),Response_18_Model%>%coef(),Response_19_Model%>%coef(),Response_20_Model%>%coef(),Response_21_Model%>%coef(),Response_22_Model%>%coef(),Response_23_Model%>%coef(),Response_24_Model%>%coef(),Response_25_Model%>%coef(),Response_26_Model%>%coef(),Response_27_Model%>%coef())%>%mutate(across(is.numeric, round, digits=3))

colnames(Coefficients)<-c(names(RT_Datentabelle[6:32]))
```

I know, this is horrible, but I was not able to do this with paste0().
I tried it as follows:

```
Response_Models<-paste0("Response_",1:27,"_Model%>%coef()",collapse = ",")
```

the output was:

```
[1] "Response_1_Model%>%coef(),Response_2_Model%>%coef(),Response_3_Model%>%coef(),Response_4_Model%>%coef(),Response_5_Model%>%coef(),Response_6_Model%>%coef(),Response_7_Model%>%coef(),Response_8_Model%>%coef(),Response_9_Model%>%coef(),Response_10_Model%>%coef(),Response_11_Model%>%coef(),Response_12_Model%>%coef(),Response_13_Model%>%coef(),Response_14_Model%>%coef(),Response_15_Model%>%coef(),Response_16_Model%>%coef(),Response_17_Model%>%coef(),Response_18_Model%>%coef(),Response_19_Model%>%coef(),Response_20_Model%>%coef(),Response_21_Model%>%coef(),Response_22_Model%>%coef(),Response_23_Model%>%coef(),Response_24_Model%>%coef(),Response_25_Model%>%coef(),Response_26_Model%>%coef(),Response_27_Model%>%coef()"
```

so there are at least three problems in my code:

- how can I realize a sequence of the select(), lm model and naming?
- I couldn´t find a solution for updating the factors (a,b,c,d) after selecting new columns except of writing them down again
- how can I paste a "real code" and not only the text to get the coefficients in my example?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the comment from Miss.Alpha I tried a nest() and map() approach and it worked quite well starting from a tidy data frame.

```
df_tidy<-df%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Y1:Y27,names_to = "Y", values_to = "value")
df_nest_lm<-df_tidy%>%
  nest(data= -Y)%>%
  mutate(fit= map(data,~lm(.x$value~.x$X1+.x$X2+.x$X3+.x$X4+.x$X1:.x$X2+.x$X1:.x$X3+.x$X1:.x$X4+.x$X2:.x$X3+.x$X2:.x$X4+.x$X3:.x$X4+I(.x$X1^2)+I(.x$X2^2)+I(.x$X3^2)+I(.x$X4^2),data= .x)),
  tidied = map(fit, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
```

Of course I want to get rid of the ugly formula, but I cannot paste it like this:

```
a <- '.x$X1'
b <- '.x$X2'
c <- '.x$X3'
d <- '.x$X4'
y <- '.x$value'

f<- as.formula(paste(y, paste(a,b,c,d,
                                    paste0(a,":",c(b,c,d),collapse = "+"),
                                    paste0(b,":",c(c,d),collapse = "+"),
                                    paste0(c,":",d),
                                    paste0("I(",c(a,b,c,d),"^2)",sep="",collapse = "+"),
                                      sep = "+"),
                                    sep = "~"))
df_nest_lm<-df_tidy%>%
  nest(data= -Y)%>%
  mutate(fit= map(data,~lm(formula=f,data= .x)),
  tidied = map(fit, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
```

I always get the error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `fit`. i `fit = map(data, ~lm(formula = f, data = .x))`. x Objekt '.x' not found

Does anybody can explain why its not working although the formula is the same as above?

Comment: You can fit multiple models at once if you have the same predictors. Just do cbind(y1, y2, ...) on the LHS of the formula.

Comment: You can use the nest() and unnest() functions in your pipes and the broom package in order to get neat results.

Comment: Since you are using the same formula for each model, why not just define it as `f <- value ~ x1 + x2 + ...`, basically the same as your formula defined at the very beginning. It should work. @Marcel

Comment: @ekoam - man, thank you. I was totally lost with the ".x$" so I did not realised.
when I just ddo 
a <- X1
its working. Thanks for your help guys and girls!

Comment: Just make a function that takes an integer as input and performs your code. Then map over `6:8` (replace `select(..., 6:8)` with `select(..., x)`) and you will get a list of the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one way:

```r
# Define formula
formula<- y~a+b+c+d+a:b+a:c+a:d+b:c+b:d+c:d+I(a^2)+I(b^2)+I(c^2)+I(d^2)
# Define a function that takes the x:th variable
my_reg <- function(x, formula, dataframe){
Response_Data <- dataframe%>%
  dplyr::select(2:5,x)
a <- Response_Data$X1
b <- Response_Data$X2
c <- Response_Data$X3
d <- Response_Data$X4
y <- Response_Data[[5]]
lm(formula,Response_Data)
}
# Make one model for each x:th variable
map(6:8, my_reg, formula, dataframe)
```